# unresolved variable d3.event.translate and d3.event.scale

Tags: d3.js, svg, zooming

I am trying to implement the zoom functionality in d3. It is implemented in angular 2 and D3 version is 3.5.17.

```
//This is where I initialize the tree layout 
ngOnInit() {
    this.tree = d3.layout.tree().size([this.height, this.width]);
    this.svg = d3.select("#body").append("div")
      .classed("svg-container", true)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + this.width + " " + this.height)
      .attr("width", 10 * (this.width + this.margin.right + this.margin.left))
      .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
      .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([-8, 8]).on("zoom", this.zoom))
      .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
}

//following is the zoom function 
public zoom = () => {
    this.svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  };
```

However, I get compilation error 'unresolved variable d3.event.translate and d3.event.scale' for d3.event.translate and d3.event.scale variables. I am wondering why is the error or if I am something missing.

Comment: How can anyone be able to help you without: 1.seeing your code; 2. knowing the error you've got?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I am sorry, I edited the question. It is just the annoying compilation error.

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of others visiting this page. In D3.js version 5 the d3.event.translate has logically been changed to d3.event.transfrom. So in new library:

```
scale = d3.event.transform.k
Xtranslation = d3.event.transform.x
Ytranslation = d3.event.transform.y
```

So writing your Zoom and Pan functions accordingly would work.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the answer, but it might be related to the bundler that you are using. There is a "gotcha" listed in the D3v4 documentation (yes, I know you're using v3.x.x, but it might still apply) regarding the `d3.event` within bundlers:

https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#event